# Is unscheduled, on-boot chkdsk behavior like this normal?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I haven't been able to find a conclusive answer for this question, so I thought I'd ask it myself...

My Win7 PC has been running all but bad the past year or so I've owned it until today. I was trying to install a few dependencies for atom.io, when my PC froze. I rebooted the computer to find an unexpected chkdsk scan. I waited for a bit, and a few messages popped up, such as:

```
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file segment xxxxxx
Deleting index entry xxxxxx in index $I30 of file yyyyyy
```

A few other things came up as well, but I was not able to capture them. I believe the gist was something about "orphaned files", and something about free space being marked as allocated in the volume bitmap.

I'm genuinely worried currently, as this has never happened before. In the research I've found, I've seen two sides: one being "It's fine, just let it sit", and the other being "Back up your disk while you still can- the end is near". I don't know which one to believe, and wanted a second opinion before doing anything.

**Update during writing:** My computer seems to be booting normally now- however I am still concerned for the health of my hard drive. Anything you guys could offer would be great. Thank you.

**Update 2:** I now have access to the Event Viewer, and have created a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/d8czRY8c) with the chkdsk log's contents.

Comment: Any grammatical or spelling mistakes can be attributed to me having to use my iPhone to type this out.

Comment: When in doubt, back up your hard drive.

Comment: @Cfinley I'll see if I can. Typically I would on a whim, but I am running under a 2 TB HDD with about half of it full, and no other medium readily available for backups.

Comment: 1 or 2 TB drives are pretty cheap nowadays. You could at least back up your important files on a flash drive. Or Dropbox, Google Drive, or any free online file sync.

Comment: @Cfinley Alright, I'll get on that. I'll leave this open, though, just in case...

Comment: Someone might have a better solution for you (as all I did was tell you to back up your data). Typically, when I have a bad feeling about a drive, I back it up, change its role (like from OS installation to general, unimportant files) and watch it.

Comment: @Cfinley Got it- I'll try that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was trying to install ...

That implies the PC was in the process of writing onto the disk.

ChkDisk coming in on the reboot is expected and normal behaviour, and from what you have typed I cannot tell there being a true problem, other than your half finished installation.

You may have entries in the system logs that will show you at least some detail on what chkdisk actually did.

If you re-run chkdisk and it tells all is OK (no changes), then you should not need to worry.

Comment: I'll rerun chkdsk then, and see. I was thinking the install might be part of it, but I wasn't quite sure. The PC hanging in the middle of the install is what got me.

Comment: [It appears everything is fine now](http://pastebin.com/0ZmHtqqC). Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe the problem was the reboot in the midst of the install. There were data yet to be written to disk.

Comment: I believe that was it as well. I do have a question, though: if, while running the install in question, the PC froze and would not accept any input, should I attempt to restart the install? Or should I leave it and not try?

Comment: Retry, you might end up with a repeat though. The outcome depends entirely on the software you're running (the install).

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot. Funny thing: it was a Microsoft product, I believe- a patch for Visual Studio.

Comment: ... as it is NOW, you have a half done install - you might need to check what that means in terms of disk use for starters. I have not "hacked" on W7 in this way so cannot recommend any software for this.